# Reduce Duplicate Records In Multi-Value Join SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Backstory:
I have created a bunch of stored procedures that analyze my client's data.  I am reviewing a list of vendors and trying to identify possible duplicates.  It works pretty well, but each record has 2 possible addresses, and I'm getting duplicate results when matches are found in both addresses.  Ideally I'd just need the records to appear in the results once.

Process:
I created a "clean" version of the address where I remove special characters and normalize  to USPS standards.  This helps me match West v W v W. or PO Box v P.O. Box v P O Box etc.  I then take all of the distinct address values from both addresses (`[cleanAddress]` and `[cleanRemit_Address]`) and put into a master list.  I then compare to the source table with a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to determine which addresses appear more than once.  Lastly I take that final list of addresses that appear more than once and combine it with the source data for output.

Problem:
If you view the results near the bottom you'll see that I have 2 sets of dupes that are nearly identical except for some slight differences in the addresses.  Both the `Address` and `Remit_Address` are essentially the same so it finds a match on BOTH the `[cleanAddress]` and `[cleanRemit_Address]` values for "SouthWestern Medical" and "NERO CO" so both sets of dupes appear twice in the list instead of once (see the desired results at the bottom).
I need to match `[cleanAddress]` OR `[cleanRemit_Address]` but I don't know how to limit each record appearing once in the results.

- SSMS 18
- SQL Server 2019

Queries:

```
--SQL (Address List): Combines all addresses for a master list of all addresses in the table
SELECT * INTO [address_list] FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [NewAdd] FROM 
      (
        SELECT  DISTINCT [cleanAddress] AS [NewAdd]
          FROM [sample_data]
          WHERE 
            ( [cleanAddress] IS NOT NULL AND [cleanAddress] <> '' ) AND
            ( [Supplier_No]  IS NOT NULL  AND [Supplier_No] <> '' )
          GROUP BY [cleanAddress] 

        UNION 

        SELECT  DISTINCT [cleanRemit_Address] AS [NewAdd]
          FROM [sample_data]
          WHERE 
            ( [cleanRemit_Address] IS NOT NULL AND [cleanRemit_Address] <> '' ) AND
            ( [Supplier_No]  IS NOT NULL  AND [Supplier_No] <> '' )
          GROUP BY [cleanRemit_Address]
      ) q1
  ) q2 
ORDER BY 
  [NewAdd] 
  


--SQL (Address Dupes): Determines which addresses appear in the data more than once
SELECT * INTO [dupe_addresses] FROM (
    SELECT [NewAdd]
      FROM [address_list] n 
      LEFT JOIN [sample_data] pv ON 
      (
        ( n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress]       AND ( [Address]       <> '' AND [Address]       IS NOT NULL ) )  OR
        ( n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] <> '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
      ) 
    WHERE 
      ( [Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] <> '' ) 
    GROUP BY [NewAdd] 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) q1 
ORDER BY [NewAdd] 

 

--SQL (Address Query): Outputs the information of the matched addresses
SELECT 
  'Address Match' AS [Reason], 
  pv.[Supplier_No], 
  pv.[Name], 
  pv.[Address], 
  pv.[City], 
  pv.[State], 
  pv.[Zip], 
  pv.[Country], 
  pv.[Remit_Address], 
  pv.[Remit_City], 
  pv.[Remit_State], 
  pv.[Remit_Zip], 
  pv.[Remit_Country]
FROM 
  [dupe_addresses] n 
  LEFT JOIN [sample_data] pv 
  ON (
    (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] <> '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ) ) 
  OR 
    (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] <> '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
  ) 
WHERE 
  ( [Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] <> '' )
```

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [sample_data] (
    [Supplier_No]           varchar(255),
    [Name]                  varchar(255),
    [Address]               varchar(255),
    [City]                  varchar(255),
    [State]                 varchar(255),
    [Zip]                   varchar(255),
    [Country]               varchar(255),
    [Remit_Address]         varchar(255),
    [Remit_City]            varchar(255),
    [Remit_State]           varchar(255),
    [Remit_Zip]             varchar(255),
    [Remit_Country]         varchar(255),
    [cleanAddress]          varchar(255),
    [cleanRemit_Address]    varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT [suppliers_pk] PRIMARY KEY ([Supplier_No])
)

INSERT INTO [sample_data] VALUES
    ('1039104','Geez Companies','100 Aero Hudson Rd','Streetsboro','OH','44241','','100 Aero Hudson Road','Streetsboro','OH','44241','USA','100 Aero Hudson Rd','100 Aero Hudson Rd'),
    ('1218409','SouthWestern Medical','100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','100 W Balor Ave','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'),
    ('1243789','SouthWestern Medical','100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','100 W Balor Ave','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'),
    ('1243636','SIRI SYSTEMS','15 BRAD ROAD','WEXFORD','PA','15090','','','','','','','15 BRAD RD',''),
    ('1152482','FLEETWOOD MACK','22 WINDSOCK CT','ADDISON','IL','60101','','PO BOX 951','CHICAGO','IL','60694-5124','','22 WINDSOCK CT','PO BOX 951'),
    ('1224483','Aerospace Junction','211500 Communicate Ave','Mingo Junction','OH','43939','USA','P O Box 99','Mingo Junction','OH','43939','USA','211500 Communicate Ave','PO Box 99'),
    ('1243397','Squeezy Felt','SCHREIBER DIST','NEW KENSINGTON','PA','15068','','','','','','','SCHREIBER DIST',''),
    ('1230895','NERO CO','28 North US State Highway 99','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','PO Box 204','Cape Girardeau','MO','63702-2045','USA','28 N US State Hwy 99','PO Box 204'),
    ('1243782','NERO CO','28 North US State Highway 99','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','PO Box 204','Cape Girardeau','MO','63702-2045','USA','28 N US State Hwy 99','PO Box 204'),
    ('1135880','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS','PO BOX 2194','KANSAS CITY','MO','64121-9468','USA','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS P O BOX 2194','KANSAS CITY','MO','64121-9468','USA','PO BOX 2194','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS PO BOX 2194'),
    ('1241328','INFINITY AND BEYOND','P.O. BOX 169','GASTONIA','NC','28053-0269','USA','','','','','','PO BOX 169',''),
    ('1259522','MILES STONES','PO BOX 169','GASSTONIA','NC','28053-0269','USA','','','','','','PO BOX 169',''),
    ('1255253','AT&T','PO Box 50221','Carol Stream','IL','60197','USA','','','','','','PO Box 50221',''),
    ('1135513','AT&T','PO Box 50221','Carol Stream','IL','60197-5080','USA','','','','','','PO Box 50221',''),
    ('1119161','Machine Co, Inc','3306 N Thorne Blvd','Chattanooga','TN','','','PO BOX 5301','CHATTANOOGA','TN','37406','USA','3306 N Thorne Blvd','PO BOX 5301'),
    ('1176587','Topsy Turvy','365 Welmington Road','Chicago','IL','60606','USA','','','','','','365 Welmington Rd',''),
    ('2156671','Topsy Turvvy, Inc.','P.O. Box 55217','Columbus','OH','43081','','365 Welmington Road','Chicago','IL','60606','USA','','365 Welmington Rd')
```

Current Results:

```
Reason  Supplier_No Name    Address City    State   Zip Country Remit_Address   Remit_City  Remit_State Remit_Zip   Remit_Country
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1176587 Topsy Turvy 365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA                 
Address Match   2156671 Topsy Turvvy, Inc.  P.O. Box 55217  Columbus    OH  43081       365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA
Address Match   1241328 INFINITY AND BEYOND P.O. BOX 169    GASTONIA    NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1259522 MILES STONES    PO BOX 169  GASSTONIA   NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1255253 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197   USA                 
Address Match   1135513 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197-5080  USA                 
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA Southern Lawn Care1004 W Hale Ave   Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
```

Desired Results:

```
Reason  Supplier_No Name    Address City    State   Zip Country Remit_Address   Remit_City  Remit_State Remit_Zip   Remit_Country
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1176587 Topsy Turvy 365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA                 
Address Match   2156671 Topsy Turvvy, Inc.  P.O. Box 55217  Columbus    OH  43081       365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA
Address Match   1241328 INFINITY AND BEYOND P.O. BOX 169    GASTONIA    NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1259522 MILES STONES    PO BOX 169  GASSTONIA   NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1255253 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197   USA                 
Address Match   1135513 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197-5080  USA
```

Comment: @DaleK Yes, Supplier_No is the Unique value

Comment: @DaleK Added PK to Table so it's more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `row_number` per supplier to the final resultset and filter out only row number 1 only.

Note the `row_number` function requires an `order by` clause which is used to determine *which* of the duplicate rows you wish to keep. Change that to suit your circumstances.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        'Address Match' AS [Reason], 
        pv.[Supplier_No], 
        pv.[Name], 
        pv.[Address], 
        pv.[City], 
        pv.[State], 
        pv.[Zip], 
        pv.[Country], 
        pv.[Remit_Address], 
        pv.[Remit_City], 
        pv.[Remit_State], 
        pv.[Remit_Zip], 
        pv.[Remit_Country]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pv.[Supplier_No] ORDER BY pv.[Name]) rn
    FROM dupe_addresses n 
    LEFT JOIN sample_data pv 
        ON (
            (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] <> '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ))
            OR (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] <> '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL))
        ) 
    WHERE ([Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] <> '') 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Supplier_No, [Name];
```

Comment: I like it, however it introduces a diff issue.  In my results the dupes are grouped together so it's easy to see them, however with this approach the matching dupe record could be 
 hundreds of rows away making it extremely difficult to read.  You can't really sort by `[Address]` since it could be matched with `[Remit_Address]`

Comment: I don't understand? We're removing dupes... so you won't have multiple dupes? And as I comment in the answer, you should `order by` *whatever logic makes sense to you* - so change the `order by` logic to suit your need.

Comment: There is no good field to order on, the best ordering method was the order that it matched them in using m y query.  The two "SouthWestern Medical" records (with different Supplier IDs) were grouped together when it found a match on `[Address]`
It was very easy to look at the output and see the duplicate data.
I need a way to group the matched (dupes) together so the output is similar to what I put in Desired Output

Comment: To give you an idea, the dataset I'm working with has 122k records.  If I remove the duplicate entries there are over 25k dupes that they need to resolve.  I'd say prob 60% need to remain a dupe for one reason or another, so having that readability will me crucial for them to review in a timely manner.

Comment: Your example query doesn't have an order by at all, so the order of the results is completely unpredictable. You can see the information available to order by, you can use any logic you like, but you have to decide what that logic is in the end.

Comment: And given the wording of your question as it stands, ordering is not part of the questions, removing exact duplicates is the only question - which this answer addresses.

Comment: Name will certainly get it closer, but there are quite a few instances where the names don't match.  Company may have changed names or something.  I wasn't sure if there was a way to do something similar with the row number, but as a group number.  So the two "SouthWestern Medical" records with diff Supplier_No would have value of 1, the two A&T would have group value 2 and so on.  Then I could order by group value (and still exclude rn >1)